# Pantalla en blanco al logear (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wordpress-plugin, google-api

Ayer estaba trabajando con mi sitio sin problemas, sin embargo, en un momento se cerró mi sesión de Wordpress, cuando quiero volver a ingresar me soltaba un error de PHP; busque en google y logre solucionarlo, ahora el problema es que el reCAPTCHA (que está en un plugin) no detecta la public ni private key que ingresé, y cuando quiero iniciar sesión me suelta el siguiente mensaje de error en una pagina todo en blanco:
"To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin"

Los archivos que responden a esto son:

• *recaptchalib*

• *recaptchalib_noCaptcha*

Estos archivos son del plugin WP User FrontEnd.

Mi pagina está totalmente bloqueada y no puedo seguir trabajando, ¿Hay alguna forma de desactivar el recaptcha o de hacer que vuelva a funcionar?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: la opción nuclear para desactivar un plugin via ftp o cpanel es cambiarle el nombre a la carpeta (o borrarla). al arrancar el bootstrap lo desactiva y te deja un mensaje en el backend

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió.